# Use thmtools to add a bar left of a theorem environment

Tags: mdframed, thmtools

I’m trying to get a theorem environment, that has a title, a line break, and then the body, with a line left of it.  Something like the following:
[image: The result I’m looking for.]
I am currently using `thmtools`. I know that `thmbox` gives an "easy" way to get this, but I want to be able to access the richer possibilities of `thmtools`. In particular, I want to get a precise formatting of the head, so that simply using `thmbox` option of `thmtools` won’t do, because it does not let me do that formatting.
Currently, the code that I got to looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{mdframed,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newmdenv[
  leftmargin = 0pt,
  innerleftmargin = 1em,
  innertopmargin = 0pt,
  innerbottommargin = 0pt,
  innerrightmargin = 0pt,
  rightmargin = 0pt,
  linewidth = 0.3pt,
  topline = false,
  rightline = false,
  bottomline = false
  ]{leftbar}

    \declaretheoremstyle[
    notebraces={}{},
    headpunct=\newline,
    headformat=\NAME{} \NUMBER. \NOTE,
    % postheadhook={\begin{leftbar}},
    % prefoothook=\end{leftbar},
    ]{foostyle}
  \declaretheorem[
        name=Foo,
    style=foostyle,
    ]{fooenv}

\begin{document}
  \begin{fooenv}[Title]
    Body with stuff in it.
  \end{fooenv}
\end{document}
```

Now if I comment the pre/post hooks, I get the line break as intended. But if I uncomment them, I get the bar that I want, but I lose the line break, so that the bar also covers the "title" of the environment.
I guess I’m doing something wrong with those pre/post hooks, but I’m not expert enough to be able to tell what…

Comment: You could simply nest the theorem body  in a `leftbar` environment (`framed` package).

Comment: Related: [Simple doubt about coloring a math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/639892/5764)

Comment: @Bernard Indeed, but it looks like those hooks are exactly done to do that without having to define an extra environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the entry for `postheadhook` in the documentation of `thmtools`:

> **postheadhook** Value: LaTeX code. This code will be executed after the call to the original begin-theorem code. Note that all backends seem to delay typesetting the actual head, so code here should probably enter horizontal mode to be sure it is after the head, but this will change the spacing/wrapping behaviour if your body starts with another list.

I'm really not an expert on these things, but from what I understand, it means you should leave vertical mode in `postheadhook` for the hook to behave as you want and to be actually written after the head. And in fact, if you do that, you don't even have to add the `\newline` manually, because once the hook behaves properly, the line is automatically skipped at the start of the `leftbar` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newmdenv[
  leftmargin = 0pt,
  innerleftmargin = 1em,
  innertopmargin = 0pt,
  innerbottommargin = 0pt,
  innerrightmargin = 0pt,
  rightmargin = 0pt,
  linewidth = 0.3pt,
  topline = false,
  rightline = false,
  bottomline = false
  ]{leftbar}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  notebraces={}{},
  headpunct=,
  headformat=\NAME{} \NUMBER. \NOTE,
  postheadhook=\leavevmode\begin{leftbar},
  prefoothook=\end{leftbar},
  ]{foostyle}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Foo,
  style=foostyle,
  ]{fooenv}

\begin{document}
  \begin{fooenv}[Title]
    Body with stuff in it.
  \end{fooenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I’ve edited the question to add an example in order to make my aims clearer: I’d like to have a bar only wrapping the body, but not the title.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I edited my answer and I think now it should do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Indeed, I did not understand that part about entering horizontal mode, that’s what I was missing! Thanks :)